# How to fetch to a device in the same network?

Tags: react-native

I'm developing an app with React Native in which I need to post some data to a database through an API. I don't have the API running online yet, but I made a database on my laptop using MySQL Workbench and a basic API with NestJS. However, when I try to fetch some data from a tablet where I'm running the app, I get the following error:

Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection (id: 0):
TypeError: Network request failed

The URL I'm fetching is something like this: IP-address-of-my-laptop:3000/movements

I'm sure the IP I'm fetching is OK because when I put it in the browser it returns the right response. I think this has something to do with not using HTTP or HTTPS, but how can I handle this?

Comment: your device and laptop are connected to the same network?

Comment: Yes, they are. As I said, I can access to the API through the tablet's browser.

Comment: Is this the FormData API?

Comment: No, I just use a function and fetch to post the data to an API running on my laptop